# reading a empty cell, gives object reference error

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

When I read a cell by doing
         Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value.ToString();

I get a error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What would be a good way to check for null and then assign the value, without having to have a "if" statement.

Comment: This question is not too related to LINQ

Comment: Why are you avoiding `if` statement? What prevents you from checking ` Worksheets.Cells[x,y].value` on null?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 string strValue = Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value==null ? string.Empty : Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value.ToString();
```

or

```
object objValue = Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value ?? string.Empty
```