# Error get value null in Excel MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I am using the following:

```
using (ExcelPackage ExcelPackage p = new ())
```

To open the excel worksheet and getting the values ​​of the cells as follows

```
string ap = ws.Cells[Lin, 12].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

But when the cell is empty presenting me this error, as I do so that when the cell is empty it ternha the null value. Estrou needing grab values ​​from several cells having value or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for a null value and substitute an empty string using code like this:

```
string strValue = Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value==null ? string.Empty : Worksheets.Cells[2,5].value.ToString();
```

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964271/reading-a-empty-cell-gives-object-reference-error)

Answer (score 1):

```
string ap = (ws.Cells[Lin, 12].Value??"").ToString().Trim();
```